# Как сделать что бы бот не выводил роль everyone?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Как сделать что бы бот не писал роль everyone в embed?

```
emb.add_field(name="Роли на сервере:", value=",".join(m.mention for m in member.roles),inline=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте условие, чтобы имя роли не было равно `@everyone`:

Вот так:

```
m.mention for m in member.roles if m.name != '@everyone'
```

Полностью так:

```
emb.add_field(name="Роли на сервере:", value=",".join(m.mention for m in member.roles if m.name != '@everyone'),inline=False)
```